# SSE2 SHA1 Problems

Tags: c, sse, sha, intrinsics

I am trying to implement SHA1 with SSE2 instructions in C.
The initialization seems to work, but if i try

```
round1(testhashe, testhasha, testhashb, testhashc, testhashd, loadConstant(b[z]));
```

as first round of my algorithm, i get errors. Constants and Values before are checked to be right, but the last value will be wrong. My Macros are

```
#define rotthirty(val) (_mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_epi32(val,30),_mm_srli_epi32(val,2)))

#define f1(b,c,d) (_mm_xor_si128(d,_mm_and_si128(b, _mm_xor_si128(c, d))))

// Round functions
#define round1(A,B,C,D,E,w) \
temp = rotthirty(A);\
temp = _mm_add_epi32(temp,f1(B, C, D));\
temp = _mm_add_epi32(temp,k1);\
temp = _mm_add_epi32(temp,w);\
E = _mm_add_epi32(temp, E);\
B = rotthirty(B);\
```

These worked before i changed to the SSE2 functions without problems, i just changed the operators to functions. What am i doing wrong?

Output after this function from with intrinsics and 4 sha calculations at a time

```
Vector: 67452301 67452301 67452301 67452301
Vector: 7bf36ae2 7bf36ae2 7bf36ae2 7bf36ae2
Vector: 98badcfe 98badcfe 98badcfe 98badcfe
Vector: 10325476 10325476 10325476 10325476
Vector: 734fe2b5 724fe2b5 8b4ee2b5 8a4ee2b5
```

which except the last line contains the right values, as can be seen in executing SSE2 free working code after Round1

```
67452301
7bf36ae2
98badcfe
10325476
122fa21
```

Comment: Make the macros inline functions (which they really should be anyway) and then you can step through the code in your debugger to see where things are going astray.

Comment: Based on the snippet above, you are missing some preamble that's part of the SSE implementations I have seen. The preamble swaps bytes in the words to prepare them for presentation to the SHA functions. For example, `[A B C D][E F G H]` is permuted to `[A B E F][C D G H]` (IIRC). Also see [Noloader | GitHub](https://github.com/noloader/SHA-Intrinsics). It provides SHA using C intrinsics for x86 and ARMv8. The code is in public domain so it is about as difficult to use as copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of rot 30 it had to be rot 5 of A.
But also, if someone else faces this problem i wanted to adress @jww answer, as it seems to be a missconception i heard some times.
If you use only SSE2 intrinsics, you can not use those mentioned SHA functions, as those were not part of this. You do not have to swap the byte pattern by loading the values into the vectors, this can stay as shown above